# Free Distillation

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Consider this example.
Take a reverse osmosis filter,and the outlet is an hose long 8km with distilled water inside. Let the apparatus sink deep in the ocean for 8Km. Now you have a long vertical hose with pure water inside,and the reverse osmosis filter at the bottom of ocean. Pure water exert 800Kg of pressure from inside,while in the outside we have 1,035Kg per 8000m ,828Kg of pressure. In a perfect world the salty water should naturally be separated from salt and emerge through the hose. Few months ago i did some math to understand if it is possible do "that",separating through containers the water so that at the base there is only a situation of 1bar-28bar and not 800bar-828bar. I put inside the compressibility of water too that at this pressure is important,and i computated a solid possibility to distillate water with only the different weight of two columns of water. I come up with an idea that with two, 350m of columns of water, we are able to produce energy...problem is that would cost 600€ per Kw/h due the expensive filters. I red somewhere that the sand is able too to filter salty water...in that case the system would be remarkable

Comment: Because i don't need a 100% distilled water in the 2nd case

Comment: Interesting concept, ... but what is your question? This appears to be a statement of an idea. Are you asking if this is feasible  or just posting an idea?

Comment: About the sand...does she really behave like an osmotic filter? I red she behave so in Ethidorpha,a book.

Comment: FWIW you get a "free"  ~350psi pressure differential just due to the fresh/salt density difference if you built your desalinization plant at the bottom of the Marianas trench. As far as I know salt water desalination requires even more pressure than that, so this isn't working anyway.

Comment: i think just 3 or 4 bars more than the theoretical needed pressure to reverse osmosis can be enough

Comment: doc,what sources are you using?

Comment: now there is only a column 50m tall with water+fructose

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you are really asking, but it seems it is something about getting "free" reverse osmosis by using the pressure sufficiently deep in the ocean instead of having to spend energy in pumping to create that pressure.

Yes, you can use pressure from ocean depth to overcome the osmotic pressure.  However, then the de-salinated water must be at surface pressure.  That means you spend the energy pumping the clean water to the surface instead of pushing the salty water against the membrane.

There is no free lunch.  You're going to pay for the flow volume times the pressure across the membrane one way or another.

Comment: Looks like perpetual motion...